# Error in getting class name in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code fragment in HTML

```
<ul class="orderedList">
    <li class="il l1">Appathon 2k14</li>
    <li class="il l2">Da Vinci Code</li>
    <li class="il l3">Java Beans</li>
    <li class="il l4">Gigabyte Wars</li>
    <li class="il l5">Spin A Web</li>
</ul>
```

I was having event handlers for each list item in my jquery script like this :

```
$(".l1").click(function x() {
    alert("Description : \n " + eventsDescription[0] + "\n\nLocation : \n" + loc[0]);
});
$(".l2").click(function x() {
    alert("Description : \n " + eventsDescription[1] + "\n\nLocation : \n" + loc[1]);
});
$(".l3").click(function x() {
    alert("Description : \n " + eventsDescription[2] + "\n\nLocation : \n" + loc[2]);
});
$(".l4").click(function x() {
    alert("Description : \n " + eventsDescription[3] + "\n\nLocation : \n" + loc[3]);
});
$(".l5").click(function x() {
    alert("Description : \n " + eventsDescription[4] + "\n\nLocation : \n" + loc[4]);
});
```

Now I was thinking to optimize my logic like this :

```
$(".il").click(function x() {
    alert($(".il").attr("class"));
});
```

As **'il'** is a class present in each tag (list item) , when I click on any list item then it should return me the name of the class. My problem is that when I click on any list item, I get result in alert dialog as **'l1 il'**.

According to my code, I think I should get **'l2 il'** by clicking on second item and so on for rest of the items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `$(this)` reference,

```
$(".il").click(function x() { alert($(this).attr("class")); });
```

In your code you are invoking `.attr()` over an element collection, that results in retrieving the class names of the element which is present at the `0` index in that collection.

Comment: this is second time, you are beating me to it today!

Answer (score 0):

Aravind code is write. u want another option try this

`$(".orderedList li").click(function() { alert($(this).attr("class")); });`